# Unable to access mysql from other directory

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

where do I need to configure to access MySQL client from any directory as of now I am able to access  as `usr/mysql/bin/mysql -uroot -ppassword db` in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set your `PATH` environment variable to include the `/usr/mysql/bin` directory. For a one off, that takes effect immediately (but disappears when you log out), you use the following in your current shell:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/mysql/bin
```

For a permanent change, you can set it either globally for the computer by editing `/etc/environment`, or just for your user by editing (or creating) `~/.pam_environment` or `~/.profile` (changes take effect next time you log in). See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables